# Passing Query String on to another page

Tags: javascript

Need to pass url parameters onto another page using js.

I am redirecting a to another url using location.href

I want to take any parameters that are on the original url and pass on to the forwarding url.

For example  :  www.mypage.com?email=test@email.com&source=search&location=ca

would be passed on to www.newpagemypage.com?email=test@email.com&source=search&location=ca

What is the best way to pass on all of the parameters?  Not sure if I need to parse out one by one and use the ones I need or just pass on all that are in the string.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: look at window.location.search

Comment: i wonder if this would work:  var params = window.location.search;
console.log ('test.com'+params);
</script>

Comment: that is close but you will need a trailing slash after `.com/`

Answer (score 1):

From CSS-tricks.com:

JavaScript can access the current URL in parts. For this URL:

http://css-tricks.com/example/index.html?s=flexbox

```
window.location.protocol = "http:"
window.location.host = "css-tricks.com"
window.location.pathname = "example/index.html"
window.location.search = "?s=flexbox"
```